# What is the meaning of "stream" in SimpleStreamFilter?

Tags: weka

I have encountered the SimpleStreamFilter in Weka, and I'm not sure how it differs from a SimpleFilter. In what sense is it a "stream"?

There are at least two senses of "stream" in Java: 1) Input/output streams that are used to read/write to/from a file, for example. 2) The Java 8 streams API

Does "Stream" in Weka refer to either of these, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question soon after I posted this: https://weka.wikispaces.com/Writing+your+own+Filter+(post+3.5.3)

In short, it doesn't refer to either sense of the term "stream" from Java. Stream filters "can start producing output right away and the data just passes through while being modified" as opposed to batch filters which "need to see the whole dataset before they can start processing it, which they do in one go."